# Creating SQL Trigger (insert or update) which will take data from one table and will put to another database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, tridion

I have got one table with name `Links` with fields

```
[PUBLICATION_ID],
[PAGE_ID],
[COMPONENT_ID],
[COMPONENT_TEMPLATE_ID],
[COMPONENT_TEMPLATE_PRIORITY],
[COMPONENT_POSITION],[URL]
```

in database `Tridion_Broker`

I want to create one SQL Trigger on insert/update which will take data from "Links" table for fields `[PUBLICATION_ID], [URL]` and put it to different database (`GoogleLinks`) and table `MyLinks`.

**EDIT**:
My Implementation is as below:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Update_Google_List;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Google_List AFTER INSERT , UPDATE 
    ON Tridion_Broker.dbo.Links
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO GoogleLinks.dbo.MyLinks (PUBLICATION_ID, URL)
SELECT DISTINCT PUBLICATION_ID as n,URL as u 
FROM Tridion_Broker.dbo.Links
WHERE Page_ID =@PageID 
AND Component_Template_Priority >0 
AND PUBLICATION_ID NOT IN(232,481) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM MyLinks as g 
WHERE g.PUBLICATION_ID = Links.PUBLICATION_ID
)
ORDER BY PUBLICATION_ID
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @OMG I have added the code tried, please suggest what changes can be done for best performance increase, actually I am looking for database performance.

Comment: You could simply pull the values from the insert table that the trigger has access to and grab insert it into your other table.

Comment: Are you sure this is for SQL Server? The syntax in your trigger does not look like something I have seen before.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, there might be some syntax typo as it was written only when I was posting the question.

Comment: Then I suggest you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx?ppud=4). It will help you a lot. Has the syntax you need and some sample triggers that you can look at.

Comment: No one else has pointed this out yet, so I will. This is a *bad* idea. Databases are "independent" within a database system - one may be available when others aren't, or recovery operations on a pair of databases may not leave them "in sync". You should avoid performing cross database work within triggers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a database item, modifying the database model, etc.. invalidates the support contract as far as I know.

I recommend you double check before proceed with this approach.

You can achieve the same scenario with a Deployer/Broker extension.
In that case you write the linking information in a different table without touching the datamodel.

The Deployer/Broker extension is a supported scenario and works pretty well.

Comment: Any example how to implement Deployer/Broker extension use?

Comment: Check the link sent by JRW in this thread, contains an example of how to create Deployer Extensions

Answer (score 2):

A sample of the extensions Miguel mentions can be found here:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_1.aspx